# Wiring question converting 120to 240

Tags: wiring, receptacle

Here's my question since it maybe confusing. 
Correctly there is a 12/2 with a ground running from panel in basement to the second floor AC. The outlet for the AC was wired 120v 20amp. I am going to install a ductless mini split and need 15amp 240v. So what I want to do is change the single pole breaker to a two pole breaker move the neutral to the breaker tape it red and change the outlet to a disconnect. So far I have no issues doing this.

My question or concern is how can I made sure there's no additional outlets/lights Daisy chained before the end of the line before I make it 240v. I obviously checked the normal ways and have turned the breaker off for 3 months and haven't noticed anything not working.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, sounds legit.  Generally since the circuit served the A/C *before*, it is typical for those to be dedicated circuits and thus homeruns.  If there are onward wires, you'll know when you open up the socket.

You can fit a 15A breaker and NEMA 6-15 recep(s).  Feel free to use a dual 6-15 so you can just keep the same faceplate.

Or, you can fit a 20A breaker, and fit either a) any number of NEMA 6-20 sockets, or b) two or more NEMA 6-15 sockets.

Oh, one more thing.  Code requires that a receptacle exist within 6' of any point along walls (following the walls around corners, not straightlining).  **You must make sure eliminating this 120V socket doesn't make you fall short of minimums**.  If it doesn't, that's good evidence that the socket was installed specifically for the A/C, and may have even been 240V once upon a time.